# Find expected value for this problem!

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

***Question:*** Two players are playing a game: there are $n$ pictures of famous celebrities in a box whose names are written behind it. Each time a picture will be taken out of the box and one of the players (who's faster) will guess who's that celebrity; if the answer is correct, the player will be given $1$ point, and if it's wrong, they will put the picture in the bin.
Assume the time it will take for one of the players to answer it to be exponential independent variables with parameters $\lambda$ and $\gamma$ for player 1 and player 2, respectively. Also, the probability of a correct answer to a picture for each player would be $p$ and $q$ respectively.
a) calculate $E$ and $var$ for game's duration.
b) What is the $E$ for player 1's score?

---

***My Attempts:*** time it takes for players to answer in each round has an exponential distribution. so its pdf is:
$\lambda e^{- \lambda x}$  if $\lambda <= \gamma$
$\gamma e^{-\gamma x}$ if $\gamma < \lambda$

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? Or, if you're stuck, can you describe how or where? This question is largely just a computation so it's hard to give meaningful hints without just telling you to do the calculation

Comment: @StephenDonovan this topic is new for me and I don't know how to do the computation when it has too many variables

Comment: Okay, can you show me how you've tried to set the computation up? If you're stuck, I would start by considering one round at a time: I would say the duration of any given round should be the lower of the response times of the two players, would you agree? Based on this, can you find a cdf (and consequently a pdf) for the duration of a single round?

Comment: Not exactly: even if one player is on average faster than the other, the slower player can sometimes answer first, right? I would recommend starting from computing $P(\text{duration } \leq x) = P(X_1 \leq x \cup X_2 \leq x),$ which will give you a cdf for the duration. Then, you can differentiate to obtain a pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $t>0$ let $N(t)$ denote the total number of guesses made on $[0,t]$.

The distribution of the time made between consecutive guesses is the minimum of two independent exponential random variables, one being $\exp(\lambda)$ and the other being $\exp(\gamma)$. Hence $N(t)\sim \text{Poisson}\left((\lambda + \gamma)t\right)$.

Each guess can be described in one of four ways.

- Player #1 guesses correctly with probability $p\cdot \frac{\lambda}{\lambda +\gamma}$
- Player #2 guesses correctly with probability $q\cdot \frac{\gamma}{\lambda + \gamma}$
- Player #1 guesses incorrectly with probability $(1-p)\cdot \frac{\lambda}{\lambda +\gamma}$
- Player #2 guesses incorrectly with probability $(1-q)\cdot \frac{\gamma}{\lambda + \gamma}$

The above analysis suggests that $N(t)$ splits as $S_1(t)+S_2(t)+F_1(t)+F_2(t)$ where $S_1(t)\sim \text{Poisson}\left(p\lambda t\right),S_2(t)\sim \text{Poisson}\left(q\gamma t\right)$ are the number of successful guesses made by Player #1/Player #2 on $[0,t]$ while $F_1(t)\sim \text{Poisson}\left((1-p)\lambda t\right),F_2(t)\sim \text{Poisson}\left((1-q)\gamma t\right)$ are the number of unsuccessful guesses made by Player #1/Player #2 on $[0,t]$.

The duration of the game is the arrival time of the $n^{\text{th}}$ arrival in a Poisson process with rate $\frac{\mathbb{E}\left(S_1(t)+S_2(t)\right)}{t}=p\lambda + q\gamma$ which is identially distributed as a sum of $n$ iid $\exp(p\lambda + q\gamma)$ random variables. So the expected duration is $\frac{n}{p\lambda + q\gamma}$ and the variance is $\frac{n}{(p\lambda + q\gamma)^2}$.

By realizing that $S_1(t)|S_1(t)+S_2(t)=n\sim \text{Binomial}\left(n,\frac{p\lambda }{p\lambda + q\gamma}\right)$ we see Player #1's expected score is $\frac{np\lambda }{p\lambda + q\gamma}$